# mongo lookup function doesn't work as expected

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 study collections inside 1 db:

```
> show collections
  customers
  housing
```

Here is some outcome of each collection:
Collection customers:

```
> db.customers.find({"address.zip_code" : 22212}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d28452ed5d4d54e8686fb5"),
    "first" : "Jimmy",
    "last" : "Bishop",
    "email" : "jbishop2s@youku.com",
    "dob" : ISODate("1977-07-31T17:50:22Z"),
    "address" : {
            "street" : {
                    "name" : "Shasta",
                    "suffix" : "Terrace",
                    "number" : "9"
            },
            "city" : "Arlington",
            "state" : "Virginia",
            "zip_code" : 22212
    },
    "user_name" : "jbishop2s",
    "package" : "Basic",
    "prio_support" : true,
    "registered_on" : ISODate("2013-08-13T02:41:03Z"),
    "transactions" : 45,
    "pet" : "manatee",
    "number_pets" : 2
}
```

Collection housing:

```
> db.housing.find({"Zip Codes" : 22212}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4311926c8b851306f35eaa"),
    "Community Area Name" : "Washington Heights",
    "Community Area Number" : 73,
    "Property Type" : "Senior",
    "Property Name" : "Senior Suites of Washington Heights",
    "Address" : "848 W. 103rd St.",
    "Zip Code" : 60643,
    "Phone Number" : "773-233-1333",
    "Management Company" : "Senior Lifestyle Corp.",
    "Units" : 82,
    "Location" : "(41.7070094274, -87.6447816603)",
    "Historical Wards 2003-2015" : 45,
    "Wards" : 22,
    "Community Areas" : 72,
    "Zip Codes" : 22212,
    "Census Tracts" : 594
}
```

As you can see, there is at least 1 document i each collections, where "db.housing.Zip Codes" == "db.customers.address.zip_code".

I want to make the following query to show columns from first and from second collections in one json:

On SQL statement it will be something like that:

```
SELECT c.user_name,
       c.email,
       h.Address,
       h.Location
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN housing h ON c.address.zip_code = h.Zip Codes
WHERE c.package = 'Basic'
AND ROWNUM <= 5
ORDER BY c.registered_on DESC
```

I prepared the following MQL statement:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "package": "Basic" } },
  { "$sort": { "registered_on": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 5 },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "housing",
    "localField": "address.zip_code",   
    "foreignField": "Zip Codes",
    "as": "zcode"
  } },
  { 
      "$unwind": "$zcode" 
  },
  { "$project": {
    "user_name": 1,
    "email": 1,
    "zcode.Address": 1,
    "zcode.Location": 1
  } }
]);
```

But it returns me 0 documents in response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using right db for aggregate. I tried and seems like its working fine
https://mongoplayground.net/p/NnBgN3DHfvh

Comment: There are `$match` and `$limit` stages before the `$lookup` - may be that zip code data is filtered in those stages.

Comment: The aggregation is quite far from the SQL snippet. It does outer join, so if you have 0 documents returned blame the $match, not $lookup. Also, the aggregation can return much more than 5 documents if zip code in the housing collection is not unique whilst the SQL snippet return no more than 5 records ever.